# Play Framework version file not found when building from Source

Tags: playframework

I use the following commands to build Play:

```
git clone git://github.com/playframework/play.git
cd play/framework
ant
```

But I can't build a new Play project:

[image]

It prompts the lack of version files.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find your Play's version within `project/plugins.sbt` file:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.13")`

As you can see, my application version is `2.6.13`.

Also I recommend to install [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) build tool, then you can simply use the Play's seed project :

```
sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

then after following the steps to name your projects and versions to use, you can run your application by using the following command:

```
sbt clean compile run
```

Then you should be able to see your app running on `http://localhost:9000`

Note that the "seed" was a Scala project, you can use the Java seed as well.